# The "GenerateResource" task failed unexpectedly C# Windows Form and DevExpress

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

I had created some Windows `Form projects` in C# by visual studio 2015 using `DevExpressComponents` and there was no problem. But after a while I reinstalled windows and visual studio and tried to run those projects again. But this time I faced with the error:

`The "GenerateResource" task failed unexpectedly.`

The previous answers could not solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

After a while searching I got the point.

At first when I was writing codes with `DevExpressComponents` and `Visual Studio 2015` just after installing `Visual Studio 2015` I installed update 1 for `Visual Studio`, and then wrote my codes with that.

But after intalling a fresh windows and `Visual Studio`, I forgot to install update 1 for `Visual Studio` and tried to open codes which were using `Visual Studio update 1` and `DevExpressComponents` with the `Visual Studio 2015` that was not updated and the was the cause of this error.

When again I installed update 1 for `Visual Studio` I could easily open previous projects without any error.